# Jenkins text not auto-wrapping (causes text field stretching)

Tags: jenkins

The text fields for some of the jobs have stretched beyond the screen bounds. It's still possible to see the text but scrolling is required (annoying).

The effect happens when only one of the text fields contains text that exceeds the normal screen bounds.

Instead of wrapping to the next line, the text keeps going and takes the screen bounds with it.

These screenshots show what's going on:

[image]
[image]

Is there some sort of configuration that I need to do to make this useable?

**The Jenkins version is 1.635**

Comment: I believe this is reported as JENKINS-29632: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29632

Comment: indeed this appears to be the same issue.